# Why is my attempt to build OpenSSL on Windows using Visual Studio tools failing?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, openssl

I am trying to build openssl libs. I cloned a repo from GitHub https://github.com/openssl/openssl

And now using a "command line" of Visual Studio 2013. This command line:[image]

I use next commands:
cd C:\Programs\openssl - go to the folder with openssl repo

perl Configure VC-WIN64A --prefix=C:\Programs\openssl-build - actually, I have no idea what this command exectly do, but all manuals talks it need. This command has next output

[image]

And "Yes, I have 'Perl', of course I installed 'Perl'"

And the next (and the last) command, which I write ts just simple "nmake". The last becouse the output of this command has some "fatal errors", which doesn't let me continue installation[image]

As you see, the main error is "fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'". As I know, the parametr machine type can be supplied in properties of Solution in Microsoft Visual Studio GUI, but how to set it from command line I have no idea, and openssl doesn't represented by Microsoft Visual Studio Solution, which can be open by MS Visual Studio.

So, maybe somebody knows how to set this property from command line, or, maybe, this error doesn't depends from this and somebody know how to solve this problem.

I hope for your help. Please, guys, second day I try to solve this, you are my last chance!!

Comment: You `Configure` you are building 64-bit, but you opened a cmd.exe environment suitable for 32 bit builds. *IF* you have a 64-bit OS, you need *VS2013 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt*. Also, why are you trying to build a development version of OpenSSL?

Comment: @SinanÜnür Unfortunately it doesn't help. Nothing changes.

Comment: Please state the errors. The text on the picture is too small to read. In addition, the text cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors. Please state the exact version of Windows, and be sure to include if its X86 or X64. Finally, state what cpu the developer prompt is providing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did. First, I opened a command prompt for 64-bit builds:

```
$ cl
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 18.00.40629 for x64
```

Then, I downloaded the [current 1.1 release tarball](https://www.openssl.org/source/). There is no reason to mess with development versions unless you are actually developing OpenSSL and you are capable of debugging problems in development versions.

```
$ curl -O https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.0e.tar.gz
$ tar xvf openssl-1.1.0e.tar.gz
$ cd openssl-1.1.0e
```

At this point, ***I read `INSTALL`*** which I recommend you also do instead of saying "*I have no idea what this command exectly do*". Once you read `INSTALL`, you will know what the command actually does.

```
$ perl Configure --prefix=%TEMP%\openssl VC-WIN64A
$ nmake
```

This gave me no errors, so I went ahead and issued

```
$ nmake test
```

which gave me

```
Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 12.00.21005.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        set SRCTOP=.
        set BLDTOP=.
        set PERL=C:\opt\perl\5.24.1\bin\perl.exe
        set OPENSSL_DEBUG_MEMORY=on
        "C:\opt\perl\5.24.1\bin\perl.exe" ".\test\run_tests.pl"
test\recipes\01-test_abort.t ............ ok
test\recipes\01-test_sanity.t ........... ok
test\recipes\01-test_symbol_presence.t .. ok
...
test\recipes\90-test_sslapi.t ........... ok
test\recipes\90-test_threads.t .......... ok
test\recipes\90-test_v3name.t ........... ok
All tests successful.
Files=91, Tests=433, 100 wallclock secs ( 0.66 usr +  0.27 sys =  0.92 CPU)
Result: PASS
```

At this point, I am pretty certain `nmake install` would also have worked, but I did not want to replace anything on my system.

You do not have a Perl or programming related problem.

Comment: nmake test and nmake install end with the same error message as 'nmake'. It doesn't work too

Comment: That's because you are not following the steps exactly.

Answer (score -3):

I think you forgot to run the `ms\do_ms.bat` file produced by the Configure script.

Below is the script that I use for building OpenSSL on my PC.

Prerequisites:

1. Install Perl on your PC.  I think I used ActivePerl, but I suspect any version will do.
2. Install NASM.  http://www.nasm.us/
3. Install Visual Studio

Then save the following script to file called `bldenv.cmd`

```
REM ######################################
REM MODIFY THESE VARIABLES BELOW TO POINT TO YOUR NASM, PERL, and VISUAL STUDIO PATHS
REM Base Variables
SET _BLD_NASM=c:\nasm\bin
SET _BLD_PERL=c:\perl64\bin
SET _BLD_VSTUDIO=c:\vstudio

REM ######################################


Echo Initializing the Visual Studio Build environment
call %_BLD_VSTUDIO%\VC\vcvarsall.bat x86

Echo adding Perl to Path
set PATH=%_BLD_PERL%;%PATH%

Echo Adding NASM to Path
set PATH=%_BLD_NASM%;%PATH%

echo #######################################
echo Build environment is ready
echo TO BUILD:
echo     perl Configure VC-WIN32    (or perl Configure debug-VC-WIN32)
echo     ms\do_nasm.bat
echo     nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak      (or nmake -f ms\nt.mak for a static lib)
echo #######################################
```

Then to build:

1. Open up a clean command shell window.  Preferably your PATH environment is already "clean" and doesn't contain Visual Studio.  Also your environment should not have any `LIB` or `INCLUDE` values set.  (Type `set` at the command prompt.  If you don't see an entry for LIB or INCLUDE yet that's good).
2. cd to the directory of your openssl sources.  Copy the bldenv.cmd script above to this directory.

   Run the script above (bldenv.cmd)

   Then run: `ms\do_nasm.bat`

   Followed by: `nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak`

That should do it.

Comment: Nope, wrong diagnosis. `ms\do_ms.bat` only applies in 1.0.x builds. He is building `1.1.1-dev`.  Read the current [INSTALL](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/3556b83ea2a00d0dd3e4f1ec38adb6837553e451/INSTALL#L93) instead of giving incorrect and outdated answers.

Comment: Then maybe the OP should just switch to OpenSSL 1.0.2.  :)